# How to Always select a certain value 1st sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

say i have a TABLE with the values

1,2,2,3,4 and ALL

in the SAME column

and I then

```
SELECT DISTINCT

value

FROM table
```

How would I go about always selecting 'All' 1st ?

or atleast ordering it that 'All' is 1st.

**NOTE**: The column is a VARCHAR(x)

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Strategy
FROM @Strategy
ORDER BY case when Strategy = 'All' then 0 else 1 end, 
Strategy DESC
```

This is my query currently

Comment: `ORDER BY case when value = 'ALL' then 0 else 1 end, value`

Comment: @jarlh or ORDER BY value = 'ALL' DESC

Comment: @EmersonDallagnol, of course,  but not all dbms support that construction.

Comment: @jarlh yea, i tried your one but i keep getting    
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @jarlh note the "table" above is actually 100% how my table looks

Comment: I don't understand your error message. Don't you select the column you order by? Can you edit the question and add you current query - with the ORDER BY?

Comment: Looks just fine. ANSI SQL compliant. Which dbms are you using, that doesn't accept it?

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server 2012

Comment: @EmersonDallagnol, Your solution will place NULL values first. I'd rather suggest ORDER BY value <> 'ALL' :-) Furthermore this solution will not work on all RDBMS because some require the values in the ORDER BY clause to be present in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose correct keyword (DISTINCT) and correct expression (ORDER BY CASE WHEN ... END) for each individual question. The trick is to solve the questions one by one instead of once.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
    FROM (VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('ALL')) AS T1(Strategy)
) AS T2
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Strategy = 'ALL' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Strategy;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this instance just use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM TABLE ORDER BY Value Desc
```

Comment: this gives wrong result as desc, so starting is good , but later record wrongly display

Comment: In fairness to @ChrisChurch though the OP didn't specify that the order of the subsequent items mattered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` (instead of `DISTINCT`) with @jarlh 's suggestion for the `ORDER BY` clause in the comments above (tweaked ever so slightly).

```
SELECT 
    Strategy
FROM 
    @Strategy
GROUP BY 
    Strategy
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN Strategy = 'All' THEN 0 ELSE Strategy END
```

Or by continuing to use `DISTINCT` you can move the `CASE` statement to the `SELECT` clause to create a new column to use in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Strategy
    ,CASE WHEN Strategy = 'All' THEN 0 ELSE Strategy END AS SortOrder 
FROM 
    @Strategy
ORDER BY 
    SortOrder
```

Or if the order of the subsequent items doesn't matter just keep it simple as @ChrisChurch suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
Declare @table table (id varchar(max))

Insert into @table values ('1'),('2'),('2'),('All'),('3'),('4')

select * from @table

--select * from @table order by id 

select * from @table order by case when id = 'All' then 0 else id end
```

Another twist, suppose you have 2 varchar entry still this logic work as

```
Declare @table table (id varchar(max))

Insert into @table values ('1'),('2'),('2'),('All'),('3'),('4'),('Select')

select * from @table

select * from @table order by id 

select * from @table order by case when id in ( 'All' , 'Select') then 0 else id end
```